# How to fetch with new #Predicate macro by Enum property

Tags: swift, swift-data

I'm trying to fetch some results with the new [#Predicate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/predicate) macro. The problem appears when I try to use an `enum` property inside the predicate. Does anyone know if it can be done or if this is a bug?

**XCode 15 beta 4**

Fetch 1:

```swift
let predicate = #Predicate<ModelA> { $0.type == ModelA.ModelAType.a }
```

Fetch 2:

```swift
let predicate = #Predicate<ModelA> { $0.type.rawValue == ModelA.ModelAType.a.rawValue }
```

Model:

```swift
@Model final class ModelA: Codable {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: Int64 = 0
    enum ModelAType: Int, CaseIterable, Codable { case a = 1, b }
    var type: ModelAType = ModelAType.a
}
```

Errors:

> Type 'ModelA.Type' cannot conform to 'StandardPredicateExpression'
> Type 'ModelA.Type' cannot conform to 'PredicateExpression'
> Cannot infer key path type from context; consider explicitly specifying a root type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Xcode 15.2 this doesn't seem to work at all if you want to use an enum in a predicate, a workaround is to store the raw value of the enum directly and use a computed property to convert between the stored value and the enum type.

---

What worked for me in this situation was to define a constant for the raw value and use that constant in the predicate

```
let aValue = ModelA.ModelAType.a.rawValue
let predicate = #Predicate<ModelA> { $0.type.rawValue == aValue }
```

I am not sure why this is needed but hopefully it’s a beta thing that will change soon

Comment: doesn't seem to work on XCode 15.1 beta 3 and simulator 17.2

Comment: @AndroidGecko Seems we have a regression, I can't make it work either even though I tried several different variants.

Comment: Also doesnt work for me with Xcode 15.2 and Simulator 17.2